# variable dimension table

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors, variable

(A *very* simplified version of my code:)

How can I create a `Table[]` with a variable number of dimensions, e.g.:

```
Table[foo,{i1,3},{i2,3},...,{iN,3}]
```

where `N` is an argument sent into a `Module[]`?

I have tried *many* things, including `Sequence[]` to try to rid of outermost braces (of the sort-of `List[]` after `foo`) -- nada.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the post and include one of the *many* things you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Evaluate` at the right point, and may use indices like `i[n]`. For example:

```
With[{dim = 4, level = 3},
 Flatten[
    Table[i[1], Evaluate[Sequence@@Table[{i[n], level}, {n, dim}]]],
    dim - 1
  ]
]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, \
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

The `i[1]` argument is just an example. You can access any index `i[k]` in this expression. Another example is

```
With[{dim = 3, level = 2},
  Flatten[
    Table[f[i[2], i[3]]^i[1], Evaluate[Sequence@@Table[{i[n], level}, {n, dim}]]],
    dim - 1
  ]
]
(* {f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[1, 1]^2, f[1, 2]^2, f[2, 1]^2, 
    f[2, 2]^2} *)
```

Comment: This is _just_ what I needed.  I _thought_ (and just looked again now) that I had used `Evaluate[]` and `Sequence[]` in just this order, but I guess it must have been slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

```
table[m_, n_] := Module[{dims = ConstantArray[m , n]}, Array[foo, dims]]

table[2, 4] // MatrixForm /@ # & // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

```
table[3, 3] // MatrixForm /@ # & // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Comment: I had forgotten about `Array[]` -- thanx. But I needed a fancier set of values for the indices.