# Variable dimension tables with variable ranges

Tags: list-manipulation, hold, sequence

I need to construct a table that has variable dimension and **variable** ranges (see for tables with variable dimensions and *constant* ranges, e.g., [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152283/variable-dimension-table)).

Suppose there is a list `list` and I'd like to build a table whose form is

```
Table[expr, {x1, 1, Length@list}, {x2, 1, Length@(list[[x1]])}, ..., {xn, 1, Length@list[[x1, x2, ..., xn-1]]}],
```

where `n` is an integer equal to or less than the depth of `list`.

What I already tried is

```
list={{{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}}}; (*an example*)
var = Table[Symbol["$x" <> ToString@i], {i, Depth@list-1}];
range = Table[
   If[j == 1,
    {var[[j]], Hold@Length[list]},
    {var[[j]], Hold@Length[Part[list, Sequence @@ var[[;; j - 1]]]]}
    ]
   , {j, Length@var}];

(*range=={{$x1, Hold[Length[list]]}, 
{$x2, Hold[Length[list[[Sequence @@ var[[1 ;; j - 1]]]]]]}, 
{$x3, Hold[Length[list[[Sequence @@ var[[1 ;; j - 1]]]]]]}, 
{$x4, Hold[Length[list[[Sequence @@ var[[1 ;; j - 1]]]]]]}, 
{$x5, Hold[Length[list[[Sequence @@ var[[1 ;; j - 1]]]]]]}}*)
```

and

```
Table[expr, Sequence@@range]
```

but since I did not release `Hold`, this does not work.

Please tell me how can I use `ReleaseHold` or `Evaluate` appropriately in this case.

**EDIT**
Actually, I forgot that I can use `Dimensions` to specify each range. However, I leave this question because still I don't understand how can I use `ReleaseHold`.

Comment: Another suggestion: table expression with iterators of the form `Table[operator, {i, 1, Length@ expression}]` can often be advantageously replaced by `operator /@ expression`. Since mapping doesn't require explicit knowledge of the size of the expression, it's much easier to handle variable-length cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit tricky. You need to assemble the iteration specification first and then insert it into a Table command.

For an example we first create some data:

```
n = 3;
list = Array[RandomInteger[{1, 9}] &, {3, 4, 5}]
```

The we define a function that gives us the length to iterate over:

```
getLength[d : {_Integer ...}] := Length[list[[Sequence @@ d]]];
```

Then we define the variables we need:

```
vars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}];
```

Next we can create the iteration specifications:

```
iter = Table[{vars[[i]], getLength[Range[i - 1]]}, {i, 2, n}];
PrependTo[iter, {x1, Length[list]}];
```

Finally we insert this into a Table (note, Table has the attribute HoldAll, what makes the Evaluate necessary):

```
Table[vars, Evaluate[Sequence @@ iter]]
```

[image]